# Bootstrap carousel in wagtail does not cycle

Tags: bootstrap-4, wagtail

I have a carousel with three images:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for loop_cycle in self.carousel_images.all %}
            {% image loop_cycle.carousel_image fill-900x100 as img %}
            <p>{{ img.url }}</p>
            <div class="carousel-item{% if forloop.counter ==  1 %} active{% endif %}">
<!--                    <img src="{{ img.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ img.alt }}">-->
                {{ forloop.counter }} &nbsp {{ img.url }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

All three images are loaded into the carousel, but only one is shown (depending on the value of the comparison (x) in

```
if forloop.counter ==  x
```

Clicking on the previous and next icons has no effect (tested in Firefox and Epiphany).

What might be wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend putting together a test page independently of Wagtail, in plain HTML - then you'll be able to tell whether the problem is on the Bootstrap side, or in the Wagtail/Django template code not producing the HTML you need, and then Wagtail or Bootstrap experts here will be able to advise accordingly.

Comment: @gasman Thanks for the tip. I've tried the html (copied directly from the bootstrap carousel component) on a new page and it works. However the identical html  does not work on the wagtail page. I've updated the bootstrap css page and that makes no differeence

Comment: @gasman So it looks like something in the bootstrap code is wrong. But what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @gasman's strategy I solved it. I compared the two cases of html.

I was missing the Bootstrap line

```
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity=" ....
```

from my {# Global javascript #}  section